# How to create spatial line dataframe from encoded polylines?

Tags: r, json, encoding, polyline, google-polyline

I'm working with transportation network dataset and I want to import traffic speed data provided as JSON format.

I could read the data in R using read.scorata(). However, I couldn't covert it to a spatial dataframe to be used for further analysis. There is one field in the current dataframe which is encoded polyline. How can I convert using this field?

```
library(RSocrata)

#Loading only two rows for easy reproduction
Test_TSD <- read.socrata("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/i4gi-tjb9.json?borough=Manhattan&id=225")
```

Comment: Any help about the post!?

Comment: This package may help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlePolylines/vignettes/sfencode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`library(googlePolylines)` can decode those polylines into coordinates.

To convert to an `sf` object currently requires a couple of steps. (There are [plans](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googlePolylines/issues/41) to make this part of the googlePolylines library)

```
coords <- googlePolylines::decode( Test_TSD$encoded_poly_line )

sfg <- lapply( coords, function(x) sf::st_linestring( x = as.matrix(x) ) )

sfc <- sf::st_sfc( sfg )

sf <- sf::st_as_sf( cbind( Test_TSD, sfc ) )
```

You now have a simple feature (`sf`) object. Given `sf` is the successor to `sp` you can stop here. But, if you still need the `SpatialDataFrame` you can do

```
sp <- as( sf, "Spatial" )
```